# Hadoop Pig Query

Tags: apache-pig

Whenever I try to run this query, it returns zero records even though I know there are records that meet this criteria.

I want to find records where column 10 is equal to 0, 1, 2, or 3 *and* column 16 is equal to 4, 5, 6, or 7.

**Pig Script**:

```
newdata = FILTER data BY ((((($10==0) OR ($10==1)
                                      OR ($10==2)
                                      OR ($10==3)))) AND
                         (((($16==4)  OR ($16==5)
                                      OR ($16==6)
                                      OR ($16==7)))));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column indexes start from 0, so the 10th column will be $9 and 16th column with me $15.Try this

```
newdata = FILTER data BY ((($9==0) OR 
                           ($9==1) OR 
                           ($9==2) OR 
                           ($9==3)) 
                          AND 
                          (($15==4) OR 
                           ($15==5) OR 
                           ($15==6) OR 
                           ($15==7)));
```